# Blur background behind MAAttachedWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Just curious if this is possible.  Right now here is what a sample [`MAAttachedWindow`](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass) looks like:

[image]

However, I want to know if I can blur the background *behind* the window, like this:

[image]

Is this possible without using private APIs?

---

Request for code.  Well, here's how MAAttachedWindow works.  You just feed it a custom NSView, and it does the rest.  So, here's how I was trying to make the blur:

```
CALayer *backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];
[view setLayer:backgroundLayer];
[view setWantsLayer:YES];
CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[blurFilter setDefaults];
[view layer].backgroundFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:blurFilter];
```

Comment: Can't you use a Quartz filter for that?

Comment: @Antwan: Not sure.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: No idea.. tbh xD however I do know there are some sample projects that apply these filters to images, you might be able to apply the same filter to your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can’t do this without using private APIs. (Is my message 30 characters long yet?)

Comment: That's what I thought.  I'm going to wait a while to accept it to see if anyone else has ideas.

Comment: If you decide to go for it: http://iloveco.de/using-core-image-filters-onunder-a-nswindow/

Comment: @sbooth: Well, I'm not going to because this is an App Store app. ;)  Don't want needless rejections.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could consider doing is to not blur the stuff behind the window, but instead capture an image of the background, blur it, and then use the blurred version of as the background of your window.

Comment: You can set the background of the attached window easily using the `setBackgroundImage:` method.  The problem with this is that the window can be moved while it's open. Thus you'd have to continuously take screenshots of the background, which wouldn't do.  So, I guess this won't work.