# how to get window with semi-transparent blurred background

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nswindow

I'd like to get a window that has a semi-transparent blurred background, just like what the Terminal can do. See this video, about 30 sec in, to see what I mean: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zo8KPRY6-Mk

See an image here: http://osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/mac-os-x-lion-terminal.jpg

I've been googling for an hour, and can't get anything to work. I believe I need to somehow create a core animation layer and add a background filter, but I've been unsuccessful so far... I just see the gray background of my window. Here's the code I've got so far:

Code:

```
//  Get the content view -- everything but the titlebar.
NSView *theView = [[self window] contentView];
[theView setAlphaValue:0.5];

// Create core animation layer, with filter
CALayer *backgroundLayer = [CALayer layer];
[theView setWantsLayer:YES];
[theView setLayer:backgroundLayer]; 
CIFilter *blurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[blurFilter setDefaults];
[theView layer].backgroundFilters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:blurFilter];  
[[theView layer] setBackgroundFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:blurFilter]];
```

Any tips or examples to do what I'm trying to do?
Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for something called HUD window! Try searching on google it will help you

Comment: thanks, but i'm still not getting much. found several promising forum posts, but pointed to examples or blog posts that no longer exist.

Comment: Frankly, I doubt the blurring is easily possible w/o private APIs. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901135/blur-background-behind-maattachedwindow

Comment: There is now a working solution in recent versions of OSX/Xcode :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475551/how-can-i-use-nsvisualeffectview-to-blend-window-with-background

Answer (score 3):

no need for layers and filters, NSWindow can do it itself

```
[mywindow setOpaque:NO];
[mywindow setBackgroundColor: [NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:0.0 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.2 alpha:0.5]];
```

please do not use this, as it will alpha your title bar also (post it here just in case others need)

```
[mywindow setOpaque:NO];
[mywindow setBackgroundColor: [NSColor blackColor]];
[mywindow setAlphaValue:0.5];
```

[image]

Comment: That's weird, the first method doesn't work for me (doing it in the init). Also tried in awakeFromNib, where else should I do this (I'm in an nswindow subclass)

Comment: no, the only thing you may control is the transparency (colorful).

Comment: So, macOS Terminal will allow us to set the blur's strength. You're saying we can't do that unless we delve into the private frameworks realm? How does Terminal achieve that effect?

Answer (score 2):

For the transparency use Jiulong Zhao's suggestion.

For a blurred background use this

The call on a NSWindow :

```
[self enableBlurForWindow:self];
```

The function :

```
-(void)enableBlurForWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    //!!!! Uses private API - copied from http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2008/03/using-core-image-filters-onunder.html

    CGSConnection thisConnection;
    uint32_t compositingFilter;
    int compositingType = 1; // Under the window

    /* Make a new connection to CoreGraphics */
    CGSNewConnection(NULL, &thisConnection);

    /* Create a CoreImage filter and set it up */
    CGSNewCIFilterByName(thisConnection, (CFStringRef)@"CIGaussianBlur", &compositingFilter);
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CGSSetCIFilterValuesFromDictionary(thisConnection, compositingFilter, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);

    /* Now apply the filter to the window */
    CGSAddWindowFilter(thisConnection, [window windowNumber], compositingFilter, compositingType);
}
```

NB: It uses a private API

Comment: How is it app store safe when it uses private APIs?

Comment: http://cocoasnippets.io/cocoa/ui/nswindow/coregraphics/2014/02/27/translucent-nswindow-with-blurred-background.html this link still works

Comment: some solution without using private api?

Comment: Dont use this solution. My App rejected due to use of this API.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this in 2017 and using **Swift 4** and wanting to change your BG **Alpha** you can add the following to your custom NSWindow class:

```
self.backgroundColor = NSColor.black
self.backgroundColor = NSColor.init(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.2)
```

p.s. I do not need the blur effect yet and when I do, I'll update the answer