# How can I use NSVisualEffectView to blend window with background

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3

There seem to be a bunch of questions on this for old versions of Swift/Xcode, but for some reason it hasn't been working with the latest update. I created a NSVisualEffectView, blurryView, and added the subview to my main view:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var blurryView: NSVisualEffectView! 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //background styling
        blurryView.wantsLayer = true
        blurryView.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectBlendingMode.behindWindow
        blurryView.material = NSVisualEffectMaterial.dark
        blurryView.state = NSVisualEffectState.active

        self.view.addSubview(blurryView, positioned: NSWindowOrderingMode.above, relativeTo: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
...
}
```

But when I run it, there is no effect on the window. (when I set it to within window, and layer it on top of my other view, the blur works correctly, but I only want the window to blur.) I also tried doing the same thing in my App Delegate class, but I can't connect my window as an outlet, and therefore can't add the blurry view to the window. Here's what the code would look like:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        blurryView.wantsLayer = true
        blurryView.blendingMode = NSVisualEffectBlendingMode.withinWindow
        blurryView.material = NSVisualEffectMaterial.dark
        blurryView.state = NSVisualEffectState.active

        self.window.contentView?.addSubview(blurryView)

    }
...
}
```

To get an idea if what I'm looking for: [NSVisualEffectView Vibrancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJlW4.png)

Comment: You have blurryView as an @IBOutlet. Why do you configure it in code then. You have all options available in interface builder. Also, why are you adding your view manually as a subview?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your storyboard or xib file?

Comment: @mangerlahn https://gyazo.com/cd4ba905f733ac1040e9f2862b4d56b7. I couldn't find the option on storyboard and thats how others seemed to add it. Also relatively new to swift and xcode so could be missing something very obvious

Answer (score 10):

It works quite easy:

1. In Interface Builder drag a `NSVisualEffectView` directly as a subview of the main view of your scene.
2. In the `Properties Inspector` set `Blending Mode` to `Behind Window`
3. Add the rest of the views you need as subviews of the `NSVisualEffectView`
4. That's it, you're done

Here's an example:

[image]

`Panel 1 View Controller` is my blurred view, `Background View` is the first (non-blurred) view in my "real"view hierarchy.

Comment: That works for other projects, but for some reason when I drag a new NSVisualEffectView it just covers all of the views below it and the storyboard view gets pretty weird. https://gyazo.com/af19501f682c3687cb4ca923c6b45ff6

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5:
Simply add this to your viewWillAppear and it should work:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    // Adds transparency to the app
    view.window?.isOpaque = false
    view.window?.alphaValue = 0.98 // you can remove this line but it adds a nice effect to it
    
    let blurView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: view.bounds)
    blurView.blendingMode = .behindWindow
    blurView.material = .fullScreenUI
    blurView.state = .active
    view.window?.contentView?.addSubview(blurView)
}
```