# How can I record the MacOS screen in realtime and process the image

Tags: xcode, macos, avfoundation, metal, screen-capture

I want to record the full macOS screen, and do different things with the images, like

- calculate average colours for different regions
- re-render parts of the screen blurred in an `NSPanel` or `NSWindow`

Right now I am using `AVCaptureScreenInput` like this

```
let input = AVCaptureScreenInput(displayID: CGMainDisplayID())!
avCaptureSession.addInput(input)
let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
avCaptureSession.addOutput(output)
output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: .main)
self.avCaptureSession.startRunning()
```

The problem with this approach is that the framerate of the image seems to be pretty low, I would like to achieve 30fps+.

**What is a good approach to achieve these goals on macOS. On one hand the "fast" fetching of the image, on the other hand, the realtime processing / re-rendering of the captured image.**

#### Issue #1

The above solution with the capture session leads to unacceptable lag. This means when moving a window, the response rendering is delayed by more than 100ms. I would like to have that in real-time.

Comment: Did you set `minFrameDuration` property?

Comment: Yes. I have tried without success

Comment: is this for achieving a blurry or transparent window? If so there are better alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174918/how-to-get-window-with-semi-transparent-blurred-background

Comment: well close, i want to make an overlay, that renders the background blurred, but also scaled and manipulated

Answer (score 0):

`AVCaptureScreenInput` is post window-composition, so you'll be capturing and transforming your own effect, which is probably not what you want.

The closest thing to what you probably want is the `CGWindowListCreateImage` API, which allows you to exclude windows, including your own, however it's not an ideal "realtime" interface because the `CGImage` output is not timestamped and cannot be toll-free bridged to a texture.